# DevExpress GridView Edit Row by clicking Row

Tags: asp.net

I want to edit the data of a row in `GridView` (not inLine but `EditFormAndDisplayRow`) not only by clicking on "edit" button/link but also by clicking anywhere in the row.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm using DevExpress Controls.

Thanks,

Ricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue:

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ID"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Text"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        </Columns>
        <ClientSideEvents RowClick="s.StartEditRow(e.visibleIndex)" />
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is close, but didn't work as is for me. I made a small edit on the ClientSideEvents-RowClick attribute to make it work:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ID"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Text"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
    <ClientSideEvents RowClick="function(s,e) { s.StartEditRow(e.visibleIndex); }" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```